# Can jQuery promises be chained with Ember.RSVP.Promise's?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, promise

I need help to understand some promises logic. Here is what I want to achieve - with jQuery I make get request, then I chain it with my promise which makes some checks, my code:

http://jsbin.com/UVEpurU/1/edit

```
function checkInfoPromise(r) {
    var ok = true,
        promise = Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(ok) {
            return resolve(r);
        }
        else {
            return reject(r);
        }
        });
    return promise;
}

var requestPromise = $.get('/')
.then(function(r){
    return checkInfoPromise(r);
});

requestPromise.then(function(r) {
    console.log(r);
}).fail(function(r) {
    console.log('fail');
});
```

and it doesn't work as I expect. Documentation says they should work fine with each other, but they don't or my code is incorrect.

Same logic with jQuery+jQuery works fine:

http://jsbin.com/AYeyaxO/1/edit

And Ember+Ember works:

http://jsbin.com/iMUgiDo/1/edit

Comment: Your first example worked for me ;)

Comment: Does it print html in console? In my case it prints some javascript stuff.

Comment: My bad, it prints the promise itself and not the html D:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think the two promise implementations are chainable.  You'd want to wrap the jquery promise inside of an Ember promise.

```
var requestPromise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.get("/", resolve).fail(reject);
});
```

JSBin : http://jsbin.com/Ikubiju/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: To clarify, looking at [`$.Deferred`'s source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deferred.js) it would appear that its check for a chained promise consists of whether it's another object with a "promise" method - so it will not recognize an `Ember.RSVP.Promise` object. So no you cannot chain the two, as I also painfully discovered this morning.